# Tensorflow Deprecated Layers

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to use

```
tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column
```

and

```
tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket,
```

but they seem to be somewhere else in TF2.0. Can anyone tell me where i can find them?

I just want to know where I could find them today, or what I could use. I am preprocessing my data (multiple numeric and categorical columns) and can't get my NN to work properly

Comment: `tf.feature_column.numeric_column` , `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket`

Comment: Search `https://www.tensorflow.org`

Comment: Thank you so much idk why i've been having the hardest time finding this